# List all failed payment attempts in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Is there a way to list all failed payment attempts, regardless the payment method used?

Edit: The basic idea is to create failed payment transaction report from existing Magento order data.

Comment: have you tried getting the information from the `sales_flat_order` table in the database?

Comment: `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_payment` records only successful transactions.

Comment: when a payment is cancelled at the payment service provider side the order in Magento is generally canceled to. If that's not the case it'll be pretty hard to track

Comment: @marius I don't understand why it was put on hold, after it was answered, and subsequently accepted. I thought it was clear what was asked, and very possible to give an answer.

Comment: @ProxiBlue. OK. I reopened it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal practice for payment methods to throw an exception when a payment fails. 
This is to change the code flow, and allow the payment method to break out, and pass control back to the controller action.

An example of payment failure would be 'Insufficient Funds'.

The exception is then captured by the controller action `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveOrderAction`

The code you are looking for is:

```
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $e->getMessage();

            $gotoSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getGotoSection();
            if ($gotoSection) {
                $result['goto_section'] = $gotoSection;
                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection(null);
            }
            $updateSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getUpdateSection();
            if ($updateSection) {
                if (isset($this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection])) {
                    $updateSectionFunction = $this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection];
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => $updateSection,
                        'html' => $this->$updateSectionFunction()
                    );
                }
                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setUpdateSection(null);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
            $result['success']  = false;
            $result['error']    = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.');
        }
```

You can see that two types of exceptions are handled.

The first (`Mage_Core_Exception`) should be the controlled thrown exception, by the payment method, for the payment failure.

The second, which is a generic 'catch all' is to catch anything not handled by the payment method. Unexpected issues.

Either way, both exception catches log to exception log using `Mage::logException($e);` so generally, failed payments would appear in your exception log, if that is enabled.

I personally don't like this, as it is a false positive exception being pushed to the log, but it is how magento does it.

Now, as I said in the start, it is normal practice. I cannot say that all payment methods follow this flow (I have seen one before that does not), and also if any 3rd party checkouts follow the same flow.

Hope that helps

Comment: In other words, this means that only traces of the failed payment transactions are in the Magento log (and email).

Comment: Correct, mixed in with real exception. You can use grep to get them out.